# PHP output tour info from parts of XML

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I'm receiving an touristic XML document which is structured like this:

```
<msResult timestamp="20130507153907">
    <places>
        <place id="1000008" name="Germany" placePath="1000008"/>
        <place id="1000591" name="Berlin" placePath="10000081000591"/>
    </places>
    <rooms>
        <room id="1002" name="Standard"/>
        <room id="1042" name="Standart"/>
    </rooms>
    <foods>
        <food id="2" name="BB" description="Breakfast"/>
        <food id="1" name="No" description="No food"/>
    </foods>
    <hotels>
        <hotel categoryId="6"/>
        <hotel id="9047" placeId="1000591" name="BERLIN EXCELSIOR" categoryId="8" desc="en"/>
        <hotel id="37803" placeId="1000591" name="MARK APART" categoryId="6" desc="en"/>
     </hotels>
     <routes>
        <route id="223534">
            <point>
                <place placeId="1000591" hotelId="37803" categoryId="6" foodId="1" tourTypeIds="1" roomId="1002"/>
            </point>
         </route>
         <route id="223535">
             <point>
                 <place placeId="1000591" hotelId="9047" categoryId="8" foodId="1" tourTypeIds="1" roomId="1042"/>
             </point>
         </route>
    </routes>
    <tours>
        <group departureId="64" currencyId="2" transportIds="1" includeIds="1 2 32" include="description" exclude="" comment="" program="" transport="">
            <tourGroup duration="3" routeId="223534" statusId="3" tourTypeIds="1" dates="17.05.2013">
                <tour accomId="6" price="850" ids="1339755026"/>
            </tourGroup>
        </group>
        <group departureId="64" currencyId="2" transportIds="1" includeIds="1 2 32" include="descriptiin" exclude="" comment="" program="" transport="">
            <tourGroup duration="3" routeId="223534" statusId="3" tourTypeIds="1" dates="31.05.2013">
                <tour accomId="6" price="902" ids="1339755024"/>
            </tourGroup>
        </group>
        <group departureId="64" currencyId="2" transportIds="1" includeIds="1 2 32" include="description" exclude="" comment="" program="" transport="">
            <tourGroup duration="3" routeId="223535" statusId="3" tourTypeIds="1" dates="17.05.2013">
                <tour accomId="6" price="981" ids="1339755027"/>
            </tourGroup>
        </group>
    </tours>
</msResult>
```

I need to output each tour like this:

**City name | Hotel name | Room type | Food type | Start Date | Duration | Price**

My current PHP code is like this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($out);

foreach ($xml->places->place as $place) {
?>
<h5><?php echo $place["name"]; ?> - 
<?php
}

foreach ($xml->tours->group as $group) {
?>
Date: <?php echo $group->tourGroup["dates"]; ?> - 
Days: <?php echo $group->tourGroup["duration"]; ?> - 
Price: $<?php echo $group->tourGroup->tour["price"];
}
```

This works, but unfortunately it outputs only separate XML values.

To get the whole structure properly I need to associate the non-constant value `"routeId=xxx"` in `<tourGroup>` with the same value in `<route id="xxx">` from which I can then take the `"id"` in `<place placeId="xxx">` and output the `"name"` from `<places>``<place id="xxx" name="...">`, and then do the same for `<hotelId="xxx">` and output the `"name"` from `<hotels>``<hotel id="xxx" name="...">` and so on for `<roomId>` and `<foodId>`. I hope that makes a bit of sense.

Unfortunately I just can't get my head around this and my PHP knowledge is pretty basic, but if someone can point me in the right direction, I'd really appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: the XML is not valid, closing root `</msResult>` missing. Apart from that: what a fine mess ;-)

Comment: Yes, it is a mess :) The XML is valid, closing root is there, I just forgot to add it here, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A little heads-up for starters, your XML is not [well formed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XML_Introduction#.22Correct.22_XML_%28Valid_and_Well-formed%29) as it's missing the closing `</msResult>` root tag.

XML is far from being an optimal solution for what you want, my advice would be to store this info in a relational database and work from there with simple queries.

Nevertheless I've coded up a solution just for the fun of it, so you can see how XPath can help you relate data between the nodes:

```
<?php
    $xml = <<<XML
<msResult timestamp="20130507153907">
    <places>
        <place id="1000008" name="Germany" placePath="1000008"/>
        <place id="1000591" name="Berlin" placePath="10000081000591"/>
    </places>
    <rooms>
        <room id="1002" name="Standard"/>
        <room id="1042" name="Standart"/>
    </rooms>
    <foods>
        <food id="2" name="BB" description="Breakfast"/>
        <food id="1" name="No" description="No food"/>
    </foods>
    <hotels>
        <hotel categoryId="6"/>
        <hotel id="9047" placeId="1000591" name="BERLIN EXCELSIOR" categoryId="8" desc="en"/>
        <hotel id="37803" placeId="1000591" name="MARK APART" categoryId="6" desc="en"/>
     </hotels>
     <routes>
        <route id="223534">
            <point>
                <place placeId="1000591" hotelId="37803" categoryId="6" foodId="1" tourTypeIds="1" roomId="1002"/>
            </point>
         </route>
         <route id="223535">
             <point>
                 <place placeId="1000591" hotelId="9047" categoryId="8" foodId="1" tourTypeIds="1" roomId="1042"/>
             </point>
         </route>
    </routes>
    <tours>
        <group departureId="64" currencyId="2" transportIds="1" includeIds="1 2 32" include="description" exclude="" comment="" program="" transport="">
            <tourGroup duration="3" routeId="223534" statusId="3" tourTypeIds="1" dates="17.05.2013">
                <tour accomId="6" price="850" ids="1339755026"/>
            </tourGroup>
        </group>
        <group departureId="64" currencyId="2" transportIds="1" includeIds="1 2 32" include="descriptiin" exclude="" comment="" program="" transport="">
            <tourGroup duration="3" routeId="223534" statusId="3" tourTypeIds="1" dates="31.05.2013">
                <tour accomId="6" price="902" ids="1339755024"/>
            </tourGroup>
        </group>
        <group departureId="64" currencyId="2" transportIds="1" includeIds="1 2 32" include="description" exclude="" comment="" program="" transport="">
            <tourGroup duration="3" routeId="223535" statusId="3" tourTypeIds="1" dates="17.05.2013">
                <tour accomId="6" price="981" ids="1339755027"/>
            </tourGroup>
        </group>
    </tours>
</msResult>
XML;

$sxe = simplexml_load_string($xml);

// Iterate groups
foreach ($sxe->tours->group as $group) {

    // Iterate groups' tours
    foreach ($group->tourGroup as $tourGroup) {
        $routeId = (string) $tourGroup['routeId'];
        $placeId = $sxe->xpath("//route[@id={$routeId}]/point/place/@placeId");
        $placeId = (string) $placeId[0];

        // City name
        $cityName = $sxe->xpath("//place[@id={$placeId}]/@name");
        $cityName = $cityName[0];

        // Hotel name
        $hotelName = $sxe->xpath("//hotel[@id=//route[@id={$routeId}]/point/place/@hotelId]/@name");
        $hotelName = (string) $hotelName[0];

        // Food type
        $foodType = $sxe->xpath("//food[@id=//route[@id={$routeId}]/point/place/@foodId]/@description");
        $foodType = (string) $foodType[0];

        // Room name
        $roomName = $sxe->xpath("//room[@id=//route[@id={$routeId}]/point/place/@roomId]/@name");
        $roomName = (string) $roomName[0];

        $startDate = (string) $tourGroup['dates'];
        $duration  = (string) $tourGroup['duration'];
        $price     = (string) $tourGroup->tour['price'];

        echo "$cityName - $hotelName - $roomName - $foodType - $startDate - $duration - $price\n";
    }
}
```

#### Output:

```
Berlin - MARK APART - Standard - No food - 17.05.2013 - 3 - 850
Berlin - MARK APART - Standard - No food - 31.05.2013 - 3 - 902
Berlin - BERLIN EXCELSIOR - Standart - No food - 17.05.2013 - 3 - 981
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your input! The XML I'm getting is not mine, it's a search result feed from a large touristic database that I'm connecting to through a search form on a website. I posted only part of this XML (this is just a part of the result for Berlin) and I forgot to add the closing root tag. Sorry, it was just already late at night. Unfortunately this XML is what I have to work with. I will try your solution, but seems this is a more complicated matter for an experienced programmer.

Answer (score 0):

Arrgh. My first shot at it:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assume XML in $x

// building array $data containing place, room, food, hotel, route
foreach ($xml->places->place as $place)
$data['place'][(string)$place['id']] = (string)$place['name'];

foreach ($xml->rooms->room as $room)
$data['room'][(string)$room['id']] = (string)$room['name'];

foreach ($xml->foods->food as $food)
$data['food'][(string)$food['id']] = (string)$food['name'];

foreach ($xml->hotels->hotel as $hotel)
$data['hotel'][(string)$hotel['id']] = (string)$hotel['name'];

foreach ($xml->routes->route as $route)
    $data['route'][(string)$route['id']] = array(
        'placeId' => (string)$route->point->place['placeId'],
        'hotelId' => (string)$route->point->place['hotelId'],
        'foodId'  => (string)$route->point->place['foodId'],
        'roomId'  => (string)$route->point->place['roomId']);

// looping through <tourGroup> and echoing...
foreach ($xml->tours->group as $g) {
    $rid = (int)$g->tourGroup['routeId'];
    echo $data['place'][$data['route'][$rid]['placeId']] . " | ";
    echo $data['hotel'][$data['route'][$rid]['hotelId']] . " | ";
    echo $data['room'][$data['route'][$rid]['roomId']] . " | ";
    echo $data['food'][$data['route'][$rid]['foodId']] . " | ";
    echo $g->tourGroup['dates'] . " | " . $g->tourGroup['duration'] . " | ";
    echo $g->tourGroup->tour['price'] . "<br />";
}
```

see it working: http://codepad.viper-7.com/wwgTuE

Output:

```
Berlin | MARK APART | Standard | No | 17.05.2013 | 3 | 850
Berlin | MARK APART | Standard | No | 31.05.2013 | 3 | 902
Berlin | BERLIN EXCELSIOR | Standart | No | 17.05.2013 | 3 | 981
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your input! I will try to work on it.